# hand-rolled R code for Poisson MLE

Tags: r, glm, poisson, mle

I'm attempting to write my own function to understand how the Poisson distribution behaves within a Maximum Likelihood Estimation framework (as it applies to GLM).

I'm familiar with R's handy `glm` function, but wanted to try and hand-roll some code to understand what's going on:

```
n <- 10000 # sample size
b0 <- 1.0 # intercept
b1 <- 0.2 # coefficient
x <- runif(n=n, min=0, max=1.5) # generate covariate values
lp <- b0+b1*x # linear predictor
lambda <- exp(lp) # compute lamda
y <- rpois(n=n, lambda=lambda) # generate y-values
dta <- data.frame(y=y, x=x) # generate dataset
negloglike <- function(lambda) {n*lambda-sum(x)*log(lambda) + sum(log(factorial(y)))} # build negative log-likelihood
starting.vals <- c(0,0) # one starting value for each parameter
pars <- c(b0, b1)
maxLike <- optim(par=pars,fn=negloglike, data = dta) # optimize
```

My R output when I enter `maxLike` is the following:

```
Error in fn(par, ...) : unused argument (data = list(y = c(2, 4....
```

I assume I've specified `optim` within my function incorrectly, but I'm not familiar enough with the nuts-and-bolts of MLE or constrained optimization to understand what I'm missing.

Comment: you don't show your definition of negloglike

Comment: @Dason, apologies, it's up there now.

Comment: You need `negloglike <- function(lambda) {n*lambda-sum(data$x)*log(lambda) + sum(log(factorial(data$y)))}`.  Consider `dpois(...,log=TRUE)` and `bbmle::mle2` too.

Comment: @BenBolker - you would probably want to add a data parameter there

Comment: you might also be interested in http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/chap6A.pdf

Comment: @BenBolker Are you sure you trust that author? ;)

Comment: @BenBolker -- thanks for the reference, and for making your research available and accessible for social scientists as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

optim can only use your function in a certain way.  It assumes the first parameter in your function takes in the parameters as a vector.  If you need to pass other information to this function (in your case the data) you need to have that as a parameter of your function.  Your `negloglike` function doesn't have a `data` parameter and that's what it is complaining about.  The way you have it coded you don't need one so you probably could fix your problem by just removing the data=dat part of your call to optim but I didn't test that.  Here is a small example of doing a simple MLE for just a poisson (not the glm)

```
negloglike_pois <- function(par, data){
  x <- data$x
  lambda <- par[1]

  -sum(dpois(x, lambda, log = TRUE))
}

dat <- data.frame(x = rpois(30, 5))
optim(par = 4, fn = negloglike_pois, data = dat)
mean(dat$x)

> optim(par = 4, fn = negloglike_pois, data = dat)
$par
[1] 4.833594

$value
[1] 65.7394

$counts
function gradient 
      22       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

Warning message:
In optim(par = 4, fn = negloglike_pois, data = dat) :
  one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
use "Brent" or optimize() directly
> # The "true" MLE. We didn't hit it exactly but came really close
> mean(dat$x)
[1] 4.833333
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dason. How would it look if I wanted to parameterize lambda so that I could understand how this works in a GLM framework? – Austin

Comment: Have your negloglike function have the first parameter take in a vector that contains b0 and b1 and then pull those pieces out at the top of function (like how I pull lambda out of par at the top of the example) and use them however you want after that.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the comments from Dason's answer is quite straightforward, but just in case:

```
library("data.table")

d <- data.table(id = as.character(1:100), 
                x1 = runif(100, 0, 1),
                x2 = runif(100, 0, 1))

#' the assumption is that lambda can be written as
#' log(lambda) = b1*x1 + b2*x2 
#' (In addition, could add a random component)
d[, mean := exp( 1.57*x1 + 5.86*x2 )]
#' draw a y for each of the observations
#' (rpois is not vectorized, need to use sapply)
d[, y := sapply(mean, function(x)rpois(1,x)) ]

negloglike_pois <- function(par, data){
  data <- copy(d)
  # update estimate of the mean
  data[, mean_tmp := exp( par[1]*x1 + par[2]*x2 )]
  # calculate the contribution of each observation to the likelihood
  data[, log_p := dpois(y, mean_tmp, log = T)]
  #' Now we can sum up the probabilities
  data[, -sum(log_p)]
}

optim(par = c(1,1), fn = negloglike_pois, data = d)
$par
[1] 1.554759 5.872219

$value
[1] 317.8094

$counts
function gradient 
      95       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```